# Can I control the state of the Speaker Icon with Delphi code

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, audio, icons

[image: System Tray Speaker Icon]

Is it possible to control (Enable/Disable) the Speaker Icon in Delphi Code.

Is there a registry entry for this?

Many Thanks...

Comment: Are you asking how to globally mute audio - which is what the icon state indicates?

Comment: There are actually three icons in that image relating to audio. One in the notification area, and two in the popup. I don't think any of them are within your gift to modify.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the icon that is used, or how to set the output volume? The icon will reflect the state of the volume settings.

Comment: Call [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368064(v=vs.85).aspx) method for default audio endpoint.

Comment: Some Staff members are clicking this speaker and disabling audio which I need to re-enable again.  I can control the level of sound from my app but if they disable the sound using this speaker icon i have no way of turning it back on again unless I go to the actual PC and re-enable it which is not really suitable for my needs.  I could probably hide the icon but I'm sure we have some savvy users who will know how to unhide it again.

Comment: So the question is really nothing to do the icon, but how to unmute audio in your app?

Comment: Using whatever audio API you are working with can't you `if (muted()) unmute()` ?

Comment: The icon is in fact an app that toggles sound on or off.  When clicked it has to be making a change somwhere in the system. I thought maybe the registry but I can't find any reference to it there...yet!   still searching through it though...I may be on the wrong track.

Comment: There is no problem to solve here. If the user wants to mute the computer, they will. It's not up to you to decide you want to override that. If they want to hear your sound they can unmute. Nothing to see here.

Comment: Please specify or tag required Windows version(s), specifically XP and/or Vista.

Comment: Well, you can register for [change notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368050(v=vs.85).aspx) of the default audio endpoint and whenever you notice a [mute flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370799(v=vs.85).aspx) to be set, unset it by calling mentioned `SetMute` method. Of course, you'll be _fighting_ with the user's will (but that's what you want to do). All that expects Vista or above OS.

Answer (score 2):

While it might be possible to "hide" the icon by changing a undocumented registry value, the user can unhide it again in the [tray icon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583) options so this is not really a permanent solution.

If you insist on ignoring your users desire to mute **their** machine you can unmute the volume programmatically.

On Windows XP/2003 and older you will have to use the old [mixer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756700(v=vs.85).aspx). This API is not fun to deal with and you have to remember to unmute both the Wave and master volume lines. See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4754/mixerSetControlDetails) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439009/Muting-all-microphones-on-WinXP) for inspiration.

Vista and later has a new COM based API that should be less painful to deal with. Create a instance of `IMMDeviceEnumerator` and enumerate the render endpoints (or use `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint`) and call [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368064(v=vs.85).aspx) on the device endpoint. [This example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437537/Muting-all-microphones-on-Vista-Win) should be pretty close, just translate it to Delphi. Volume can also be controlled per application so you might need to deal with that as well if your users are clever.

[Larry Ostermans blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/tag/audio/) is also a great source for help and details about this new API.

Note: As a workaround for your unmuting, the user can simply set the volume really low to get rid of your sound. There is really no way for you to know if the sound is audible at a low volume level and setting it higher just because you can would be very evil and could really hurt somebody with headphones etc.

Comment: Excellent note on evils of messing with volume.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys.  As for "messing" with Volume. No head phones in use and all systems have monitors with built in speakers which are not very loud.  When I have to relay a message to all staff , my app will set volume to 50% to alert them of the message and its importance so that they react to it immediately.  Now off to check out some of those links..   Thanks Again for the help and advice..